# Convert .apk file to .abb file without Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please how can I convert .apk to .aab without Android studio

I created an Android app using AIDE and I wanted to upload to Google Play Store and then I discovered it's only .aab file format of the app they accept.

Comment: Google play Console  accept .apk file also.

Comment: you can try it from Android Studio. it's easy

Answer (score -1):

Via gradle - without android studio, you would use task 'bundle' instead of 'assemble'

Answer (score -2):

Yes, They still accept apk files. However, Apk files are 32 bit now. For Later Android releases like 12 and above, move your Project To Android Studio. There is no option other than using android studio because there is no other ide to support it at the moment. Please Contact google If needed any more assistance.

Comment: This is false information. "Upload a valid app bundle". https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#get_started

Answer (score -2):

> 1- setup  [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)
>
> 2- open your project in Android studio
>
> 3- from `the Menu` at the top choose `Build` then `Generate Signed Bundle/APK...`

[image]

> 4- in dialog box mark at `Android App Bundle(aab)` ***and follow steps that it***

[image]

Comment: I mean, he specifically mentioned "WITHOUT" Android studio

Comment: I just recommended using android studio ...

Comment: Okay. But since he did it with AIDE which is a mobile IDE suggesting how to get the files to the PC should be included too.

Comment: Why I don't have the Gererate Signed Bundle button, just Generate Signed Apk...

Comment: which android studio version are u using for it, because new version is  not support or I couldn't find it